Flutter_Appauth - Google OAuth 2.0 for Flutter
I am implementing Google OAuth 2.0 for Flutter Android using flutter_appauth, but the browser is not redirecting the user back to the app. Do I need deep linking for this, or can I manage it through a custom URI?
I have created a Client ID for the Web application and added same redirect URL https://companyname.com/api/oauth/google/callback
I also added the domain companyname.com on the OAuth consent screen under Authorized domains
Here is my code
build.gradle
defaultConfig {

    manifestPlaceholders += [
            appAuthRedirectScheme: 'https'
    ]
    //other config
}

AndroidManifest.xml
<activity android:name="net.openid.appauth.RedirectUriReceiverActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="companyname.com" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

Flutter Code
 final FlutterAppAuth appAuth = FlutterAppAuth();

    final AuthorizationTokenResponse? result =
        await appAuth.authorizeAndExchangeCode(
      AuthorizationTokenRequest(
        'xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        'https://companyname.com/api/oauth/google/callback',
         scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email'],
         serviceConfiguration: AuthorizationServiceConfiguration(
          authorizationEndpoint: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth',
          tokenEndpoint: 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
         ),
       ),
    );
    

